# Is there documentation for Apple's Objective C/Cocoa API directly accessible through XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, api, documentation

I can't find a way to mouse over or right click Objects and their members and get more information on them than the members they contain (for objects) or the arguments they take (for methods).

Coming from a java background whenever I have a question about anything in Sun's Java API, whether it be an object (like File, or SwingWorker), or a method (like substring(), or readLine()), I can access their documentation in-line with either a ctrl-space or right click in either netbeans or eclipse.

Is there some way to do this in Xcode for Apple's Objective-C/Cocoa API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option-click the thing you want to know more about. When you hold down option (alt), you should see your cursor turn into a question mark (when hovering over a symbol that can actually provide documentation). Clicking an item brings up the relevant docs in a popover. You can drill further in using the links at the bottom of the popover.

Comment: You can also option-double-click to go straight to the documentation tab in the Organizer, skipping the popover.

Comment: Thanks very much, accepted as answer because option-click is closer to what I was looking for than the organizer window, though both answers were very helpful

Comment: If you're using a trackpad, you can also use double tap the thing with 3 fingers and it'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's an inspector on the right side of the editor that'll show quick documentation for whatever symbol the insertion point is in, so you don't always even need to go to he docs in Organizer.

[image: quick help]

Also, when your program is running you can hover over a variable and see its value. If the variable points to an object, you can see its members, and you can drill down into the members.

[image: debugging]

Answer (score 0):

There is. Go to xcode's organizer and switch to documentation section.